# Make push animate like present

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa

I am trying to push a viewController and I want to change the animation of the push. The original puch animation is flip from right/left, I need to make it from bottom, just like the animation of present.
I tried the following code, it works, but the background will be black when the viewcontroller is animating. What can I do with it?

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
animation.duration = 2.0f;
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animation.type = kCATransitionPush;
animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
[[self.navigationController.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animation"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
```

Comment: Look around. There are plenty of tutorials that help you achieve this. Check this one out. http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/

Comment: Can you tell us why you MUST use PUSH instead of PRESENT? There might be work a around the reason you need to use PUSH.

Comment: @AtifAlvi  I use push because I want to use the navigation bar. If I use present instead, I need to insert another navigation controller,  which will affect other parts of our project.

Comment: Have a look at [THIS DOCUMENT](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDwQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdevstreaming.apple.com%2Fvideos%2Fwwdc%2F2013%2F218xdx4xj2umojkv3e8dbk6i%2F218%2F218.pdf%3Fdl%3D1&ei=yJj9U5-rIYy7uASL-YCgDA&usg=AFQjCNHXmFJl2NAnH29_dtzNx2BJqh7YJA&sig2=fl60dgV5D5NtalYPc1PmaQ). Scroll down to **Interactive View Controller 
Transitions**. It is pretty advanced, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey you can use below method while pushing a controller in navigation controller with animated NO

```
- (void)animateControllerFromBottomToTop
{
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDelegate:self];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromTop];
    [animation setDuration:0.65f];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [[self.navigationController.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"AnimationFromBottomToTop"];
}
```

Comment: That's right, but I've found that the background will be black at some times during the animation. Have you found such questions?

Comment: What's more, it's not the same as present in modal completely. When we present a viewcontroller, the presenting viewcontroller won't do any animation, but it will slide out in such solutions.

Comment: To achieve an effect more similar to "Present", the type should be kCATransitionMoveIn and not kCATransitionPush

Answer (score 0):

You can use **PRESENT** and still have the **Navigation Bar**.

Let's say your base viewController is **VC1** and the next view controller which you need to push is **VC2**.
Just embed the **VC2** inside another **Navigation Controller**, then create a **Present Segue** from **VC1** to the **Navigation Controller** heaving **VC2** as its **Root**.

It will be **presented** with your required animation and will still have the **navigation bar**.
Hope it helps.